# Android track app cause overheat to device

Tags: android, gps, location

I have developed an android application which took the current location using GPS every 10 seconds, and send it to the server using socket. To achieve this I used postDelayed method to keep getting current location and send it to server.

```
myRunnable = new Runnable()    {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Location mCurrentLocation =getCurrentLocation();
        if(mCurrentLocation != null)
            sendCurrentLocationToServer(mCurrentLocation);
        Handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }};

public Location getCurrentLocation(){
    Location currentLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    return currentLocation;
}
```

but this code makes the device to overheat, and consumes the battery quickly, is there another way to achieve the same result and reduce the overheat?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use getLastKnownLocation.  Not only will it normally return null, looping calling it is an EXTREMELY inefficient way of doing things.  Instead, requestLocationUpdates, and it will call you when it has a new location.

Second, don't send the location to the server every 10 seconds.  Sending it that frequently causes your phone to keep the radio (either wifi or cellular) on constantly, which is causing your heat issue.  Sending data generates heat.  Reduce it to once every minute or so, and send up heading and speed data with the location.  If you need a more exact location the server can use speed and heading to programmatically calculate a probable location-  if needed.  Most likely you don't even really need that.